# I have 4 different teams and want to sort them descending, comparing values at different array indexes

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

First of all sorry for my English. I am a new programmer in Xcode and I have a question:

I have 4 different mutable arrays and I want to sort them descending, comparing their values at different indexes to see the team positions.

I have array 1,2,3,4

```
array1 [team1,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,4] 
array2 [team2,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,2] 
array3 [team3,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,3] 
array4 [team4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,-3]
```

the output I am looking for after sorting is

```
array1 [team1,6,0,0,0,0,8,4,4] 
array3 [team3,5,0,0,0,0,4,3,3] 
array2 [team2,5,0,0,0,0,3,1,2] 
array4 [team4,2,0,0,0,0,1,-4,-3]
```

First I want to compare the 4 arrays at index [1] to see which team has more points.

If two or more teams are tied at points, I want to compare their goal difference at index[8].

If the teams have the same goal difference, I want to compare the goals scored at index [6]
and sort the teams positions in descending order.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like something that might be easier to use dictionaries for

```
NSString * points = @"points";
NSString * goalDifference = @"goalDifference";
NSString * goalsScored = @"goalsScored";

NSDictionary * team1 = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:6], points,
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], goalDifference,
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:8], goalsScored, nil];
NSDictionary * team2 = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:5], points,
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], goalDifference,
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], goalsScored, nil];
NSDictionary * team3 = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:5], points,
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], goalDifference,
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], goalsScored, nil];
NSDictionary * team4 = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], points,
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:-3], goalDifference,
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], goalsScored, nil];

NSArray * sortedArray = [@[team1, team2, team3, team4] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary * obj1, NSDictionary * obj2) {

    // are points equal?
    if ([obj1[points] intValue] != [obj2[points] intValue]) {

        // points not equal, compare points
        if ([obj1[points] intValue] > [obj2[points] intValue])
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        else
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else {

        // points equal, check goal difference
        if ([obj1[goalDifference] intValue] != [obj2[goalDifference] intValue]) {
            // goal difference not equal, compare goal difference
            if ([obj1[goalDifference] intValue] > [obj2[goalDifference] intValue])
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
            else
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        else {
            // goal difference & points equal - check goals scored
            if ([obj1[goalsScored] intValue] != [obj2[goalsScored] intValue]) {
                // goals scored not equal, compare goals scored
                if ([obj1[goalsScored] intValue] > [obj2[goalsScored] intValue])
                    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
                else
                    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
            }
            else {
                // points, goals scored, and goal difference are all equal
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
            }
        }
    }
}];

NSLog(@"RECEIVED: %@", sortedArray);
```

If you must use arrays, replace the keys with an index ex:

```
NSMutableArray * team1;
NSMutableArray * team2;
NSMutableArray * team3;
NSMutableArray * team4;

NSArray * sortedArray = [@[team1, team2, team3, team4] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSMutableArray * obj1, NSMutableArray * obj2) {

    // are points equal?
    if ([obj1[1] intValue] != [obj2[1] intValue]) {

        // points not equal, compare points
        if ([obj1[1] intValue] > [obj2[1] intValue])
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        else
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else {

        // points equal, check goal difference
        if ([obj1[8] intValue] != [obj2[8] intValue]) {
            // goal difference not equal, compare goal difference
            if ([obj1[8] intValue] > [obj2[8] intValue])
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
            else
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        else {
            // goal difference & points equal - check goals scored
            if ([obj1[6] intValue] != [obj2[6] intValue]) {
                // goals scored not equal, compare goals scored
                if ([obj1[6] intValue] > [obj2[6] intValue])
                    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
                else
                    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
            }
            else {
                // points, goals scored, and goal difference are all equal
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
            }
        }
    }
}];

NSLog(@"RECEIVED: %@", sortedArray);
```